# How to Sync an NSDocument from Mac osx to iPad/iPhone with iCloud

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, icloud, nsdocument

I have seen iCloud Document sample code for iOS and I used it to sync a [uidocument](/questions/tagged/uidocument) to and from iCloud and now I am trying to sync iCloud with an [nsdocument](/questions/tagged/nsdocument) on a Mac OSX app which doesn't have `UIDocument`.

I tried to change `UIDocument` to `NSDocument` but all the methods of syncing with [icloud](/questions/tagged/icloud) are different. I haven't found any sample code or tutorials except for the documentation from [apple](/questions/tagged/apple) which is very confusing and not well written.

For example, the method below, from `UIDocument` on iOS does not exist in `NSDocument` on OS X:

```
//doc is an instance of subclassed UIDocument
[doc openWithCompletionHandler:nil];
```

The Apple Documentation provides this code for OS X:

```
- (void)checkIfCloudAvaliable {
    NSURL *ubiquityContainerURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                    URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]
                                   URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    if (ubiquityContainerURL == nil) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              NSLocalizedString(@"iCloud does not appear to be configured.", @""),
                              NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey, nil];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Application" code:404
                                         userInfo:dict];
        [self presentError:error modalForWindow:[self windowForSheet] delegate:nil
        didPresentSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
        return;
    }
    dest = [ubiquityContainerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:
            [[self fileURL] lastPathComponent]];
}

- (void)moveToOrFromCloud {
    dispatch_queue_t globalQueue =
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^(void) {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        NSError *error = nil;
        // Move the file.
        BOOL success = [fileManager setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:[self fileURL]
                                   destinationURL:dest error:&error];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            if (! success) {
                [self presentError:error modalForWindow:[self windowForSheet]
                          delegate:nil didPresentSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
            }
        });
    });
    [self setFileURL:dest];
    [self setFileModificationDate:nil];
}
```

How can I sync between iOS and OS X (because `NSDocument` does not exists on iOS, and `UIDocument` does not exist on OS X)? Does anyone know where I can find a sample for Mac OSX (`NSDocument` syncing)?

Comment: Not all of us find the documentation "confusing and not well written".

Comment: I used the documentation and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Alternatively - why not show some of the code that you have tried rather than looking for something you can cut and paste. You've done it for iOS - so you must have some idea of the flow.

Comment: Here you go, I pasted some code i used from the documentation that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get it working! Here's my code from the subclassed [nsdocument](/questions/tagged/nsdocument) file on OS X:

Header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface subclassedNSDocument : NSDocument

@property (strong) NSData *myData;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError 
{
    BOOL readSuccess = NO;
    if (data) 
    {
        readSuccess = YES;
        [self setMyData:data];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dataModified" 
                                                        object:self];

    return readSuccess;
}

- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError 
{
    if (!myData && outError) {
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                        code:NSFileWriteUnknownError userInfo:nil];
    }
    return myData;
}
```

and in the AppDelegate.m file:

```
#define kFILENAME @"mydocument.dox"

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
        // TODO: Load document... 
        [self loadDocument];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(dataReloaded:) 
                                                 name:@"dataModified" object:nil];
}

- (void)update_iCloud
{
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:kFILENAME];
    self.doc.myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[@"Your Data Array or any data", nil]];
    [self.doc saveToURL:ubiquitousPackage ofType:@"dox" forSaveOperation:NSSaveOperation error:nil];
}

- (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query {

    if ([query resultCount] == 1) {

        NSMetadataItem *item = [query resultAtIndex:0];
        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
        subclassedNSDocument *doc = [[subclassedNSDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url ofType:@"dox" error:nil];
        [doc setFileURL:url];
        self.doc = doc;
    } 
    else {

        NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:kFILENAME];

        dataUrls *doc = [[dataUrls alloc] init];
        [self.doc setFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
        self.doc = doc;
        [self.doc saveToURL:ubiquitousPackage ofType:@"dox" forSaveOperation:NSSaveOperation error:nil];
    }

}

- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [notification object];
    [query disableUpdates];
    [query stopQuery];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                                  object:query];

    _query = nil;

    [self loadData:query];

}

- (void)loadDocument {

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    _query = query;
    [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, kFILENAME];
    [query setPredicate:pred];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];

    [query startQuery];

}

- (void)dataReloaded:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    self.doc = notification.object;

    NSArray *arrFromCloud = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.doc.myData];

    //Update you UI with new data
}
```

The only thing that I haven't got working is that if I change the data of the document on the iPad, the Mac app doesn't call the `readFromData` method for to update from iCloud, does anyone know what I am missing?

On iOS, the equivalent method, `loadFromContents`, is called automatically on every change of the `UIDocument` in iCloud. On OS X the `readFromData` is called once on load but never called again.

Hope my code can help, for me it is working one way from Mac to iPad.

Comment: @user1173374 You should not pose more questions within an answer on StackOverflow. Instead, start a new question. In your new question you can link back to this answer for reference.

Comment: @Olof I posted the question for updating from iPad to Mac here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984512/how-to-sync-an-nsdocument-from-ipad-iphone-to-mac-osx-with-icloud

Answer (score 2):

I think `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` is what you are looking for to detect document update.

This can be used just like `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with files in addition to core data. Here is a better tutorial

http://samvermette.com/312